# Four persons with a commonality

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

All these four persons have a commonality. However, in their childhoods, persons 1, 2 and 3 missed out on an event that person 4 did not miss out on.

**What was that event (specific to their commonality)?**

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The four persons are:

> [John Byrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Byrom), 29 February 1692 - 26 September 1763
>  [Gioachino Rossini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gioachino_Rossini), 29 February 1792 - 13 November 1868
>  [Augusta Savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusta_Savage), February 29, 1892 - March 27, 1962
>  [Sean Abbott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_Abbott), born 29 February 1992

They were all ...

> ... born on the [leap day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29), **29 February** eight years before the turn of a century.

The event they missed was ...

> ... their **eighth birthday**, because the years 1700, 1800 and 1900 were not [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). The year 2000, however, was a leap year, so Sean Abbott got to celebrate his "proper" birthday on 29 Februrary.

Comment: They missed their SECOND birthday, don't you mean?

Comment: Hm. Maybe. I use birthday here to mean birthday anniversary, as is usual, not birthday quadrennial, so they miss the second birthday that can be celebrated on the day proper. They don't even miss out on it completely, it's just four years later when they are twelve. Oh, it's complicated, so I'll just say: You know what I mean.